# How does wrap_content work with an Edit Text view?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

When declaring an EditText view in an axml file (as an example), I usually specify the width of it as "wrap_content".

```
<EditText 
    android:width = "wrap_content" />
```

But it made me wonder, what happens if the user exceeds of the Edit Text view's margins? Will the margins expand due to the "wrap_content" setting? Will it stay the same and the rest of the entered input will remain invisible to the user?

One more thing is, how will the Edit Text view look without setting an hint? If I set the width to "wrap_content" and there is no input entered at the beggining (no content), would the view even appear in the application?

Basically, how warp_content works? Does it allow the view's width to change dynamically? Or is it just a "one time" setting for the first inflation of the view?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: @Josh I use Xamarin and not Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `edittext` displays default width equivalent to a character (eg, W).

My `edittext` is as follows :

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Check he image below :

[image: EditText with width "wrap_content"]

Comment: Great example. Thanks a lot!